# Position elements around a circular image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

```css
#absolute-canvas a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 4em;
  margin: -2em;
  border-radius: 100%;    
  background: black;
}
.deg0 { 
  transform: translate(12em);
} /* 12em = half the width of the wrapper */
.deg45 { 
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(12em) rotate(-45deg);
}
.deg135 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(12em) rotate(-135deg);
}
.deg180 { 
  transform: translate(-12em);
}
.deg225 { 
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(12em) rotate(-225deg);
}
.deg315 { 
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(12em) rotate(-315deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="absolute-canvas">

  <img src="./images/logoWithShadow.png" id="logo" class="img-responsive animated zoomIn" alt="" title="СП ФИНКИ" />
  <div id="nav-container">
    <a href='#' class='deg0'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg45'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg135'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg180'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg225'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg315'></a>
  </div>

</section>
```

My current solution works however when the image scales down (decreases in size) I want to keep the circles around the same image. How can I accomplish this?

Image of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

The central div is an image that's infact a circle.

Comment: Unless you have some significant backwards compatibility issues wouldn't SVG or canvas be easier?

Comment: SVG is supported in IE9+ and all other modern browsers. SVG is better equipped, more semantic and more flexible than CSS when dealing with non-rectangular elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SVG [**`<circle>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) elements you can do this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.circle-container {
  flex: 1;
}
.circle {
  color: #2F7285;
}
.circle--main {
  color: #5E66FF;
}
```

```html
<svg class="circle-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle class="circle circle--main" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="200" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="6" fill="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--one" cx="50%" cy="20%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--two" cx="75%" cy="35%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--three" cx="75%" cy="65%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--four" cx="50%" cy="80%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--five" cx="25%" cy="65%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--six" cx="25%" cy="35%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

---

If you want to include an image, you can use a SVG `pattern`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.circle-container {
  flex: 1;
}
.circle {
  color: #2F7285;
}
```

```html
<svg class="circle-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/200x200"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle class="circle circle--main" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="200" stroke-width="6" fill="url(#image)" />
  <circle class="circle circle--one" cx="50%" cy="20%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--two" cx="75%" cy="35%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--three" cx="75%" cy="65%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--four" cx="50%" cy="80%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--five" cx="25%" cy="65%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
  <circle class="circle circle--six" cx="25%" cy="35%" r="50" stroke-width="8" fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

---

Have in mind that since you are using the same shape, instead of creating different elements you could create a SVG Spritesheet and reuse the circle shape with the `<use>` tag, only if there is no deeper manipulation for each circle element.

Comment: I'm having an issue where the image is not being rendered if height and width is not set previously. Why is this happening?(I haven't used SVG before)

Comment: (the parent element's size, absolute-canvas, is 0 - is there a way to make the image part act as a regular responsive <img> ?)

Comment: You need to give the image a size, unlike HTML, SVG images default to width and height of zero.